# Comparação de atributos de objetos dentro de um laço for

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmo-de-busca, objetos, atributos

Como comparar um único item de um objeto que tem 3 espaços ou mais?
Quero fazer um sistema que, todas as vezes que o login digitado for igual a algum que já esteja armazenado em algum objeto, apareça um alerta informando que o login já esta cadastrado.

```js
//objeto
function User(login, senha) {
    this.login = login;
    this.senha = senha;
}

lista = new User(3);

//laço para comparação (NÃO SEI SE ESTA CORRETO)
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lista[i] = new User();
    lista[i].login = prompt("Digite o " + (i + 1) + "º usuário para cadastro");
    lista[i].senha = prompt("Digite a senha do " + (i + 1) + "º usuário para cadastro");
    for (var j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        if (lista[i].login == lista[j].login)) {
            alert("Login já cadastrado!");
        }
    }
}
```

CÓDIGO COMPLETO COM A PARTE QUE ESTA DANDO ERRO EM COMPARAR. SEGUE ABAIXO:

```js
/*ENUNCIADO:
Crie Uma lista de usuários(Login e Senha); Mostrar um alerta todas as vezes que o usuários digitar um login igual.*/

function User(login, senha) {
    this.login = login;
    this.senha = senha;
}

//ENTRADA DA QUANTIDADE DE CADASTROS QUE DESEJA FAZER
    var n = prompt("Entre com quanto usuários você gostaria de cadastrar");

//LAÇOS PARA POSSIVEIS ERROS DE DIGITAÇÃO
if (n >= 'a' && n <= 'z' || n >= 'A' && n <= 'Z') {
    alert("ERRO!\nEntre com um número inteiro para o cadastro dos usuários.");
    n = 0;
    var n = prompt("Entre com quanto usuários você gostaria de cadastrar");
} else if (n == "" || n == " ") {
    alert("ERRO!\nO Espaço não pode estar em branco");
    n = 0;
    var n = prompt("Entre com quanto usuários você gostaria de cadastrar");
}

//CRIAÇÃO DE UM ARRAY PARA UTULIZAR COM O ARMAZENAMENTO DE VALORES
lista = new User(n);

//LAÇO PARA ENTRADA DO LOGIN E SENHA DO CADASTRO
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lista[i] = new User();
    lista[i].login = prompt("Digite o " + (i + 1) + "º usuário para cadastro");
    while(lista[i]login ==lista[i].login) {
      alert("Login já cadastrado!");
      lista[i].login = null;
    }
    lista[i].senha = prompt("Digite a senha do " + (i + 1) + "º usuário para cadastro");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em relação a sua pergunta, uma forma geral para verificar a presença de um valor x nos atributos de objetos armazenados em um vetor, podemos usar a seguinte expressão:

```
vetor.some(elemento => elemento.atributo === x);
```

A aplicação desta expressão no caso específico segue no código abaixo. No entanto, antes gostaria de mencionar o que considero alguns problemas com o código apresentado:

- A expressão `lista = new User(3)` está incorreta, deve-se criar a lista usando `lista = []` e criar os objetos usando new `User(login, senha)`.
- O valor da variável `n` não está definido.
- Não há verificação de retorno da função `prompt()`, a qual pode retornar `null` caso clique-se em *Cancelar*. É interessante também evitar a
  entrada de strings vazias.
- No laço `for (var j = i+1; j < n; j++)`, são realizadas iterações da posição atual do vetor para frente, quando deveria-se fazer o contrário.

Por fim, aplicando a fórmula e efetuando as correções dos problemas apresentados, incluindo verificações de consistência, obtive o código abaixo:

```
function User(login, senha) {
    this.login = login;
    this.senha = senha;
}

let lista = [];
let login, senha;
let n = prompt("Quantos usuários deseja cadastrar?");;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    login = null;
    while(login == null || login == "")
    {
      login = prompt("Digite o " + (i + 1) + "º usuário para cadastro");

      if(lista.some(usuario => usuario.login === login)) {
        alert("Login já cadastrado!");
        login = null;
      }
    }

    do {
      senha = prompt("Digite a senha do " + (i + 1) + "º usuário para cadastro");
    }
    while (senha == null || senha == "");

    lista.push(new User(login, senha));
}
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta. Rodei o seu código aqui e deu tudo certo. Mas ainda existem algumas coisas que não consegui entender no seu código...
Vou editar meu comentário e por meu código completo, e depois explico a minha dúvida.

Comment: Coloquei meu segundo código que estava sendo implementado antes de ver sua resposta.
A dúvida é porque criar uma lista assim `var lista = [];` e não assim `lista = new User(n);` e depois que entra no laço for assim `lista[i] = new User();`.
Meu código esta rodando, só não consigo implementar a comparação de objetos dentro do laço for.
Se puder me explicar seu código agradeceria muito. Abraços, obrigado pela atenção. Lembrando: Sou iniciante na linguagem JavaScript.

Comment: @KayoRodrigo A função User(login, senha) é uma construtora de objetos, que conforme você definiu demanda como parâmetros "login" e "senha". Não se pode chamar esta função para se construir uma lista, ela constrói objetos do "tipo" User. Se quiser construir uma lista sem usar var lista = [ ], pode também utilizar o construtor de lista, o qual já devolve a lista com o número de elementos que você deseja: var lista = Array(3). Somente de posse da lista é que você colocará os objetos que criar nela.